# Getting header from img tag

Tags: php, http, http-headers, image

Is there any way to retrieve headers from <img> tag using PHP? The <img> has src attribute set to a randomly and dynamic generated PHP image, which sends header that I want to retrieve containing dynamic content based on content of the image.

Comment: A header that is based on the  content of the image? Are you sure? Care to provide an example of such a header?

Comment: somevar = rand(0,2); header('Some-Name',somevar); header('Content-Type','image/png'); some_image_code_that_uses_somevar;

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers are determined by the web server when they serve the image. You can override the headers by serving the content directly from PHP. However, this is much, much slower than the web server serving the image directly. Most web servers allow for configuration to determine the HTTP headers for a given file extension.

UPDATE: Add code to respond to comment.

HTML

```
<a href="/images/my-image.php?type=png" />
```

In my-image.php:

```
<?php
   if( $_REQUEST['type'] == 'png' ){
        header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
        echo file_get_contents( '/websites/mywebsite.com/web/images/my-image.jpg' );
            exit();
   }
```

More checks and code is available here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175

Comment: I don't want to override a header, I want to send my own header that depends on what's getting showed on the image.

Comment: No, that's for different thing. My image and the header I want to send are different on every execution of the script, so I can't use http_get_headers. I need to syncronize &lt;img&gt; tag with the header that will be used in different place.

Comment: What headers do you want to control? The response or request? I'm not using http_get_headers in the above code.

Comment: I want to get a variable from response.